# How to divide Data Frame on 2 separated datasets 70%/30% of unique ids taking all rows for each id in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have Data Frame in Python Pandas like below:

**Input data:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' : [999, 999, 999, 185, 185, 185, 44, 44, 44],
    'target' : [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    'event_date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03'],
    'event1': [1, 6, 11, 16, np.nan, 22, 74, 109, 52],
    'event2': [2, 7, np.nan, 17, 22, np.nan, np.nan, 10, 5],
    'event3': [3, 8, 13, 18, 23, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 99],
    'event4': [4, 9, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 11, 8, np.nan, np.nan],
    'event5': [5, np.nan, 15, 20, 25, 1, 1, 3, np.nan]
})

# Wypełnienie brakujących wartości zerami
df = df.fillna(0)
df
```

[image]

**Requirements:**

My real dataset has of course many more data, but I need to divide my dataset on 2 separate datasets (train and test) based on the following requirements:

1. For train dataset I need to take 70% of unique id from my input dataset
2. For test dataset I need to take 30% of unique id from my input dataset
3. For each new dataset I need to take all rows for each id, be aware that each id have same number of rows in my input dataset **(it cannot be the case that for some id we take only 2 rows, for other id we take 3, always taking all rows of a given id)**

**Example of needed result (of course in real data should be proportion 70% /30% of unique ids):**

***train dataset:***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' : [999, 999, 999, 185, 185, 185],
    'target' : [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    'event_date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03'],
    'event1': [1, 6, 11, 16, np.nan, 22],
    'event2': [2, 7, np.nan, 17, 22, np.nan],
    'event3': [3, 8, 13, 18, 23, np.nan],
    'event4': [4, 9, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 11],
    'event5': [5, np.nan, 15, 20, 25, 1]
})

df = df.fillna(0)
df
```

***test dataset:***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' : [44, 44, 44],
    'target' : [1, 1, 1],
    'event_date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03'],
    'event1': [74, 109, 52],
    'event2': [ np.nan, 10, 5],
    'event3': [2, np.nan, 99],
    'event4': [8, np.nan, np.nan],
    'event5': [1, 3, np.nan]
})

# Wypełnienie brakujących wartości zerami
df = df.fillna(0)
df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the duplicates with [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html), [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sample.html), then use this to build a mask with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to split the data:

```
keep = df['id'].drop_duplicates().sample(frac=0.7)

m = df['id'].isin(keep)

train = df[m]
test = df[~m]
```

Variant using a `set`:

```
import random

S = list(set(df['id']))

keep = random.sample(S, k=round(len(S)*0.7))

m = df['id'].isin(keep)
train = df[m]
test = df[~m]
```

Example output:

```
# test
    id  target  event_date  event1  event2  event3  event4  event5
0  999       1  2023-01-01     1.0     2.0     3.0     4.0     5.0
1  999       1  2023-01-02     6.0     7.0     8.0     9.0     0.0
2  999       1  2023-01-03    11.0     0.0    13.0     0.0    15.0
6   44       1  2023-01-01    74.0     0.0     2.0     8.0     1.0
7   44       1  2023-01-02   109.0    10.0     0.0     0.0     3.0
8   44       1  2023-01-03    52.0     5.0    99.0     0.0     0.0

# train
    id  target  event_date  event1  event2  event3  event4  event5
3  185       0  2023-01-01    16.0    17.0    18.0     0.0    20.0
4  185       0  2023-01-02     0.0    22.0    23.0     0.0    25.0
5  185       0  2023-01-03    22.0     0.0     0.0    11.0     1.0
```

Comment: mozway, it looks perfect, thank you, I gave best answer! :)