# How to divide Data Frame on 2 separated datasets 70%/30% based on unique combinations of values from 2 columns in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Data Frame in Python Pandas like below:

**Input data:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' : [999, 999, 999, 185, 185, 185, 44, 44, 44],
    'target' : [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    'event': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-02-03', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03'],
    'survey': ['2023-02-02', '2023-02-02', '2023-02-02', '2023-03-10', '2023-03-10', '2023-03-10', '2023-04-22', '2023-04-22', '2023-04-22'],
    'event1': [1, 6, 11, 16, np.nan, 22, 74, 109, 52],
    'event2': [2, 7, np.nan, 17, 22, np.nan, np.nan, 10, 5],
    'event3': [3, 8, 13, 18, 23, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 99],
    'event4': [4, 9, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 11, 8, np.nan, np.nan],
    'event5': [5, np.nan, 15, 20, 25, 1, 1, 3, np.nan]
})

df = df.fillna(0)
df
```

[image]

**Requirements:**

My real dataset has of course many more data, but I need to divide my dataset on 2 separate datasets (train and test) based on the following requirements:

1. For train dataset I need to take 70% of unique values from combination columns: id, survey from my input dataset
2. For test dataset I need to take 30% of unique values from combination columns: id, survey from my input dataset
3. For each new dataset (train / test) I need to take all rows for each combination columns: id, survey, be aware that each combination columns: id, survey has same number of rows in my input dataset **(it cannot be the case that for some combination columns: id, survey we take only 2 rows, for other combination columns: id, survey we take 3, always taking all rows of a given id)**

**Example of needed result (of course in real data should be proportion 70% /30% of unique combination columns: id, survey):**

**train dataset:**

[image]

**test dataset:**

[image]

Comment: The answers so far do not have the same ids in train and test. Can you update your question with an example of when that might happen?

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77428642/16343464) [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) and [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sample.html), however then use an outer [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator=True` to identify the two groups:

```
cols = ['id', 'survey']

keep = (df[cols]
        .drop_duplicates()
        .sample(frac=0.7)
        )

tmp = df.merge(keep, how='outer', indicator=True)

train = (tmp.query('_merge == "both"')
            .drop(columns='_merge')
         )
test = (tmp.query('_merge == "left_only"')
           .drop(columns='_merge')
        )
```

Example output:

```
# train
    id  target       event      survey  event1  event2  event3  event4  event5
0  999       1  2023-01-01  2023-02-02     1.0     2.0     3.0     4.0     5.0
1  999       1  2023-01-02  2023-02-02     6.0     7.0     8.0     9.0     0.0
2  999       1  2023-02-03  2023-02-02    11.0     0.0    13.0     0.0    15.0
3  185       0  2023-01-01  2023-03-10    16.0    17.0    18.0     0.0    20.0
4  185       0  2023-01-02  2023-03-10     0.0    22.0    23.0     0.0    25.0
5  185       0  2023-01-03  2023-03-10    22.0     0.0     0.0    11.0     1.0

# test
   id  target       event      survey  event1  event2  event3  event4  event5
6  44       1  2023-01-01  2023-04-22    74.0     0.0     2.0     8.0     1.0
7  44       1  2023-01-02  2023-04-22   109.0    10.0     0.0     0.0     3.0
8  44       1  2023-01-03  2023-04-22    52.0     5.0    99.0     0.0     0.0
```

Comment: mozway - one more thing, there can not be the same id in train and target, if some id is in train it can not be in test and vice versa - could you modify your code, please? :)

Answer (score 0):

df.sample method coupled with random_state parameter will let you achieve your goal. random_state parameter is required to ensure reproducibility of experiment.

Based on your comments, I think you need to ensure that if a combination of id and survey is present in train dataset, it cant be present in test dataset. I am updating my answer as shown below:

```
uniques=df[['id','survey']].drop_duplicates()
train_ids = uniques.sample(frac=0.7,random_state=42)

df_new=df.merge(train_ids,on=['id','survey'],how='left',indicator=True)
df_train=df_new.loc[df_new['_merge']=="both"].copy(deep=True)
df_test=df_new.loc[df_new['_merge']=="left_only"].copy(deep=True)
```

Comment: Pawan  - one more thing, there can not be the same id in train and target, if some id is in train it can not be in test and vice versa - could you modify your code, please? :)

Comment: @dingaro, so i believe you need a solution which will give you mutually exclusive combinations of id and survey columns in test and train datasets. If that is the case, please try the below solution: